# Vertical text center in div

Tags: html, css

Here you can show an example of my code : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwXLb/)

```
<div id="gameTimeBar-holder">
<div id="gameTimeBar"></div>
<div class="progressBarText">Actions : 852 minutes</div>
```

```
#gameTimeBar-holder{width:200px;height:15px;background:grey; position:absolute; top:45px; left:5px;}
#gameTimeBar{width:0;height:100%;background:purple;}
.progressBarText{position:absolute;z-index:10;top:0;left:0;width:100%;text-align:left; color: white;}
```

How can i vertical center my text in the div progressBarText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `line-height` to your text
try this:

```
.progressBarText{
       position:absolute;
       z-index:10;
       top:0;
       left:0; 
       width:100%; 
       line-height:15px; 
       text-align:left; 
       color: white; 
   }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwXLb/2/)

Comment: oh yes, that was simple.. thanks !

Comment: This is simply an abuse of `line-height`. What if he had multiple lines of text.

Comment: isn't necessary to downvote the right answer if your isn't the rght way but isn't ridiculous I think my answer @crush

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Your answer isn't right. Try resizing the font, and see what happens to your "vertically centered" text.

Comment: well the solution works fine for the OP example isn't specified that is a global solution for all existing font-size not? Well your downvote I repeat isn't necessary and your critic not constructive for this problem @crush

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Your answer isn't right. Period.

Comment: This is the important, the resolution of your problem :) @ClémentAndraud